# Android Toolbar no Elevation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout, android-elevation

My Main layout has a `CoordinatorLayout`, which has inside an `AppBarLayout`, `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, `Toolbar`, and a `TabLayout`.

However, The toolbar doesn't show a shadow.

This is my layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainCoordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:background="#eeeeee"
        android:clickable="true">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_behavior="torathamachane.DisableableAppBarLayoutBehavior"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout">
            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:collapsedTitleGravity="right|top"
                app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom|right"
                app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="44dp"
                app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsedTitleTextAppearance"
                app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ExpandedTitleTextAppearance"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="0dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="30dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/headerImage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
                <View
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/scrim_top"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
                <View
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="112dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/headerImage"
                    android:background="@drawable/scrim_bottom" />
                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    app:titleTextColor="@color/White"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
                    app:titleMarginTop="13dp">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/Location_Spinner_Layout"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="-15dp">
                        <include
                            android:id="@+id/toolbar_header_view"
                            layout="@layout/toolbar_header_view"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/header_view_end_margin_left"
                            android:visibility="invisible" />
                        <View
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1" />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/dateText"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/White"
                            android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textSize="13sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
              <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                  android:id="@+id/libraryTabs"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                  android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                  app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
                  android:layoutDirection="ltr"
                  android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                  app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                  android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                  app:tabMode="fixed"
                  app:tabGravity="fill" />
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

What is wrong with my layout?

Comment: Add a background color gray or black on the toolbar and if that doesn't work  add a view with the stated color and having the toolbar size placed directly below the elevated toolbar to give the shadow effect.

Comment: @Waqas Thanks, but I prefer not to use a "hack", and to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

try this i had also same problems it works for me

```
  final AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams)
            toolbar.getLayoutParams();
    params.setScrollFlags(0);
    toolbar.setLayoutParams(params);
```